# Program to Encrypt Text Depending on the Length of a Word

Tags: java, encryption, char, string-length

I wanted to make a program to encrypt text depending on its length. For example if the word was "test", then because "test" has 4 letters, it will shift each letter in the word to the 4th next letter. This would make "test" to "xiwx". I have made part of my program already. Here is it:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    string.toLowerCase();
    int charPos = 0;
    int length = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        charPos = 0;
        length = 0;
        while(!(string.charAt(i) == ' ')){
            length = charPos;
            charPos++;
        }
        length--;
        for(int j = 0; j<=length; j++){
            char cha =string.charAt(i);

            //HERE IS WHERE THE CHAR ADDING WILL HAPPEN

        }
        i++;

    }

}//end
```

Comment: You can do `char shifted = cha + 3`.  Need to take care to roll over from Z back to A.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Thilo how do i use that?

Comment: Look at other "Caesar Cipher" code, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007467/caesar-cipher-java  As you can see, you can use `c + 4 ` to "add four letters".

Comment: i know that you can just do (the letter) + length. but then it will show as the ascii number for that letter now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler way to achieve this type of encryption just by using one loop.

**Encryption:**

```
String str = "test"; // normal string

String encryptedStr = ""; // start empty then add characters

for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) // loop through each character in str

    encryptedStr += (char) (ch + str.length()); // need to cast addition to char

System.out.println("Encrypted String: " + encryptedStr); // output encrypted string
```

So the idea is to use the length() method to get the length of the string, as that's what you're adding to each character. Because each character has an ASCII integer value, we can perform math operations on them (so in this case, adding the length to each character). Then, since the result will be an integer, we must add a (char) cast to the result to convert it back to a character. Then we can concatenate this character to the empty string. If we do this with each character in the original string (by using a for loop and converting the string to a char array), we'll eventually get the encrypted string at the end.

The same idea works with **Decryption:**

```
String str = "xiwx"; // encrypted string

String decryptedStr = ""; // start empty then add characters

for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) // loop through each character in str

    decryptedStr += (char) (ch - str.length()); // need to cast subtraction to char

System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + decryptedStr); // output decrypted string
```

Except we subtract the length from each character.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: i know that you can just do (the letter) + length. but then it will show as the ascii number for that letter now...

Comment: Yeah, but in case other people want to know how it works.

Comment: i am banned from asking questions because i have low votes